# How can I open two different pylab figures from the same button from a wxpython gui?

Tags: python, wxpython, matplotlib, figure

I am new to python and I have a serious problem that I cannot overcome. I have created a gui using wxpython that has two text fields and a button. When this button is pressed I call a function that call another function which creates a pie figure according to the input in text boxes. The problem is that if the user do not close the figure and enter new values to the textboxes and press again the button, the program crash instead of showing a second figure. I tried to create different threads when the button is pressed the result is the same.

More specifically:

this are the functions that are called when the button is clicked:

def statistics_button(self,event):

```
   t=threading.Thread(target=self.m_button21OnButtonClick,args=(event,))
    t.start()
    print t    

def m_button21OnButtonClick( self, event ):

    '''some code here'''


    fig=statistics.mmr_dist(mmr1,mmr2) 

    show()
```

the statistics_button is called first and then this calls the m_button21OnButtonClick.
the statistics.mmr_dist function is the following:

```
'''some code'''
fig=pylab.figure(tit,figsize=(8,8),frameon=False)

ax=pylab.axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8])
pita=pylab.pie(db.values(), labels=tuple(db.keys()), autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True)
ti="%s-%s\n Maximum Distance = %s m\n Minimum Distance = %s m" % (ddf1.label,ddf2.label,maxdist,mindist)
title(ti, bbox={'facecolor':'0.8', 'pad':5}) 


'''some code'''

return fig
```

So far I have understood that the show() command blocks the function m_button21OnButtonClick from finishing so it cannot be called again when the button is clicked unless the figure is closed. But this is the reason I implemented different threads. Though it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this page](http://clumsyduck.com/2008/07/getting-wxpython-and-matplotlibs-pylab-to-work-together/) for advice on getting pylab to work with wxPython--which you probably shouldn't really try (see next paragraph).  The problem is that pylab uses Tkinter which is incompatible with a running copy of wxPython.

Ultimately, you should just [embed your plots in wxPython](https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/Matplotlib_EmbeddingInWx.html).  That works very well and is a better user experience anyway.

Comment: Along these lines, my preferred solution is to paint images onto PyQT QLabels. If you're married to wxPython, then go with these examples, but I've found PyQT nicer in my applications. Just a thought; Chelonian's answer is very helpful as is.

Comment: Thank you very much. This solved the problem! I just added: from matplotlib import use
use('WXAgg')  and removed the threads and now the program works as it should. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Try issuing the command `pylab.ion()` after you import pylab, and see if that lets you show multiple plots. That has always been my approach when needing to repeatedly show updating plots without closing the window.

Note that you'll need to create new figure and axes objects for each different plot window, otherwise plots will overwrite old plots.

For example, the following code works to produce two windows with different plots for me:

```
 import pylab
 pylab.ion()

 fig1 = pylab.figure()
 fig1.add_subplot(111).plot([1,2],[3,4])
 pylab.draw()

 fig2 = pylab.figure()
 fig2.add_subplot(111).plot([5,6],[10,9])
 pylab.draw()
```

**Added**

Given your follow-up comments, here is a new script that does use `show()`, but which displays the different plots each time `pylab.draw()` is called, and which leaves the plot windows showing indefinitely. It uses simple input logic to decide when to close the figures (because using `show()` means pylab won't process clicks on the windows x button), but that should be simple to add to your gui as another button or as a text field.

```
import numpy as np
import pylab
pylab.ion()

def get_fig(fig_num, some_data, some_labels):

    fig = pylab.figure(fig_num,figsize=(8,8),frameon=False)
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.set_ylim([0.1,0.8]); ax.set_xlim([0.1, 0.8]);
    ax.set_title("Quarterly Stapler Thefts")
    ax.pie(some_data, labels=some_labels, autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True);
    return fig

my_labels = ("You", "Me", "Some guy", "Bob")

# To ensure first plot is always made.
do_plot = 1; num_plots = 0;

while do_plot:
    num_plots = num_plots + 1;
    data = np.random.rand(1,4).tolist()[0]

    fig = get_fig(num_plots,data,my_labels)
    fig.canvas.draw()
    pylab.draw()

    print "Close any of the previous plots? If yes, enter its number, otherwise enter 0..."
    close_plot = raw_input()

    if int(close_plot) > 0:
        pylab.close(int(close_plot))

    print "Create another random plot? 1 for yes; 0 for no."
    do_plot = raw_input();

    # Don't allow plots to go over 10.
    if num_plots > 10:
        do_plot = 0

pylab.show()
```

Comment: I did that but when I click the button the figure appears and it instantly closes. I tried with the show(block=True) command but this has the same result as without the ion()

Comment: the show() command is the only that displays my figure. I tried also the draw that it doesn't show anything. Also in the pie example in matplotlib docs they use show(). Maybe it is a bug with the pie diagrams? I don't know...

Comment: I think you need to post more of your code then, because it sounds like a more significant error. To use interactive mode, you should not have to use `show()`, so something is going wrong before that.

Comment: For example, in your code you are using `pylab.pie()`, but you should be calling that in such a way that it gets added to the figure and axes that you've created. I think something might be going wrong there.

Comment: I updated the code above with something that ought to work for you. It works for me, creating and immediately drawing as many figures as I want, allowing me to close them selectively while others remain open. You could add any other kind of code for your program in the while-loop in my example and it should work. Worst case you have to add some extra widget to handle the close-window logic.